# How does the size of a pointer change when it is pointing at a single character and when at a dynamically declared array of long integers? C code

Tags: c

I know that an array declaration results in a block of memory being reserved, but with an array represented by a pointer this does not.  As it contains the address of the first element of the array.

But concerning how the size changes from pointing to a single long int, to a dynamically declared array of long integers, any explanation on the subject would be much appreciated.

Kind regards

Example :

```
long int *plint = 5; // size is the same as

long int *arr;

arr = (long int*)malloc(5*(sizeof(long int));
```

Is size arr is the same as size plint ?

If not how does it change size?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Pointer is a special variable, store address of another variable. Address of a variable is an Integer and will take size same as that of normal Integer variable. Consider following code snippet.

```
         char c ='a';
         char *ptr = &c;
```

Here c is character will take 1 byte and ptr is char pointer variable(not char variable). So size of ptr is same as that of size of integer.

Now,

```
         int* ptr = (int*) malloc(10*sizeof(int));
```

again size of ptr is same as that of size of integer though it's pointing to block of size (10*size of int)

Comment: Thanks.  So no matter what type the array is, be it long int, char, float etc, the pointer is storing just the addresses of other types?  

The pointer to char variable you declared, ptr, is it storing the address of the integer dynamic memory, but points to the address of its first element?  But the size is the same in all cases?

Comment: Yeah exactly. No mater what how much bytes of memory it points, at the end it will store base address of that block which will be int.

Comment: OKay, nice one Vallabh Patade.  Thanks very much

Comment: "Address of a variable is an Integer and will take size same as that of normal Integer variable." - no.

Comment: "store address of another variable" - should be "object", not "variable".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Can you please explain.?

Comment: @VallabhPatade: Logically, a pointer is not an integer, it's an unrelated type.  Its size may have nothing to do with any particular integer type.  And it's objects that have addresses.

Comment: After the `malloc`, the address stored in `ptr` is not the address of a variable. It is the address of an object, though (specifically the object that is the first element of the array allocated by `malloc`). That's why you should say that addresses are of objects, not only of variables.

Comment: *size of ptr is same as that of size of integer* NO, NO, NO!  They are not related.  For example, quite a few implementations on 64-bit machines have a 32-bit int and a 64-bit pointer.  Programmers making the assumption that the size of an int and the size of pointer are the same have caused so much grief!

Answer (score 3):

I imagine your code looks something like this:

```
long *ptr = 0;
long ra[10];
printf("%d %d\n", (int)(sizeof(ptr)), (int)(sizeof(ra)) );
```

In this case `ra` *is not a pointer*, and its size is not the size of a pointer.

`&ra[0]` is a pointer to the first element, so you could do:

```
print("%d\n", (int)(sizeof(&ra[0])));
```

You'll see that it's the same size as `ptr`.

In most cases, when you use `ra` in an expression it "decays" to a pointer to its first element. But `sizeof` is not one of those cases.

Comment: Well, I think you hit the nail on the head.. OP got confused between pointer and array base address..

Comment: So by pointing to e.g. long int *plint = 5; // size is the same as
long int *arr;

arr = (long int*)malloc(5*(sizeof(long int));

size arr is the same as size plint
?

Comment: @user1890248: StackOverflow has eaten some of the asterisks in your comment. But if you declare two variables as `long int *`, then they have the same size.

Comment: Yeh just realised that, thanks.  So even if it's dynamic array?  If so, is it just because the pointer is storing the address to the Dynamic Allocated array?  What about the pointer arr = (float *)malloc(N*sizeof(float));  as a different type, as it would just store the address, is this possible?

Comment: @user1890248: I think you need to look again at what variables actually are. They are named memory locations. They cannot ever change size according to what value is stored in that memory location. So a `long*` is always the same size regardless of whether the value it holds is the address of the first element of an array, or the address of something else, or not the address of anything (a null pointer).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **size of a pointer doesn't change**. Simple explanations is **pointer is a variable which stores the address of another object**. The actual size is platform dependent.

Comment: @Petesh I am still confused about the edit.. Are you asking a question there? If yes put it as a different question, not edit someone's answer..

Comment: "address is an integer" and "pointer is sufficient to store an integer" are misleading, at best.  In some senses, it's best not to think of pointers as integers; logically, they are completely disjoint from true integer types.

Comment: Also, it should be "pointer is a variable which stores the address of another **object**".

Comment: Thanks very much, Krishnabhadra.  Very helpful

Comment: @OliCharlesworth disagree, The question is tagged as C, and there the term **object** not used. An address of a variable is always an `unsigned int` and pointer takes a size sufficient to store integer is correct in any platform I know of..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: None of that is true.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: To clarify, the C standard does use the term "object" (it's more general than "variable"; not all objects correspond to variables).  And there's nothing that says that a pointer has to be the same size as an int (on x86-64, a pointer is 64-bit, and an int is (usually) 32-bit).

Comment: Regarding your latest edit: the document you link to is not the C specification.

Comment: Hmm.. I am still a little bit confused.. Anyway I edited the answer, removed the parts that might be wrong, so that others won't see it. Anyway has some reading to do..